# does return object from function lead to memory leak

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks

Taking the following code for example, does return object from function lead to memory leak?

I'm very curious about what happens to the object `handle` after used by the function `use_age`.

```
class Demo(object):

    def _get_mysql_handle(self):
        handle = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.conf["host"],
                             port=self.conf["port"],
                             user=self.conf["user"],
                             passwd=self.conf["passwd"],
                             db=self.conf["db"])
        return handle

    def use_age(self):
        cursor = self._get_mysql_handle().cursor()

if __name__ == "__main__":
      demo = Demo()
      demo.use_age()
```

Comment: No, why would you think that?

Comment: Thought of  `C/C++` , curious about what's the rule for python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that code won't lead to a memory leak.

CPython handles object lifetimes by reference counting. In your example the reference count drops back to 0 and the database connection object is deleted again.

- The local name `handle` in `_get_mysql_handle` is one reference, it is dropped when `_get_mysql_handle` returns.
- The stack holding the return value from `self._get_mysql_handle()` is another, it too is dropped when the expression result is completed.
- `.cursor()` is a method, so it'll have another reference for the `self` argument to that method, until the method exits.
- The return value from `.cursor()` probably stores a reference, it'll be dropped when the cursor itself is reaped. That then depends on the lifetime of the local `cursor` variable in the `use_age()` method. As a local it doesn't live beyond the `use_age()` function.

Other Python implementations use garbage collection strategies; Jython uses the Java runtime facilities, for example. The object may live a little longer, but won't 'leak'.

In Python versions < 3.4, you do need to watch out for creating circular references with custom classes that define a `__del__` method. Those are the circular references that the [`gc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) does not break. You can introspect such chains in the [`gc.garbage` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).

Comment: Then do I need to call close on the connection or leave it to the object destructor?

Comment: @luoluo: the object destructor will take care of it, but if you are relying on transactions you probably want to control when the connection closes more directly, especially if you are using Jython or IronPython.

Comment: Taking the above code for example, the connection returned by `_get_mysql_handle` is only use once, after that there should be no reference on that object. In short, in this  case, there seems to be a Implicit close. Is this true?

Comment: @luoluo: The MySQL connection object will implicitly close when the object is deleted, yes. Python ensures that it is deleted.